# python Selenium AttributeError with send_keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am making an `instagram` bot, I have successfully been able to type in the username automatically, however I am getting an Attribute type error when I want to test my password params.

Also, My username arguments are being populated into the username field on IG, but the password is just showing blank.

password field not populating:

[image]

Attribute error for sendkeys

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username).send_keys(self.username)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'



from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        #get around automated testing
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        #end of automated testing

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

        self.login()
    def login(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username).send_keys(self.username)

        self.driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password).send_keys(self.password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]').click()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ig_bot = InstagramBot('test', 'test')
```

Comment: why `.send_keys(self.username).send_keys(self.username)`?  you need  it one time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I see you have multiple send keys on username and password, Try the following*

```
def login(self):
    self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
    time.sleep(3)

    email_input = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("form input")[0]
    password_input = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("form input")[1]

    email_input.send_keys(self.username)
    password_input.send_keys(self.password)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

*make sure to add the following with your import*

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```